# Can't show an instance of an inherited Node class

Tags: javafx

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Figure figure = new Figure(50,50,100,100,400,400);
    GridPane pane = new GridPane();
    pane.getChildren().addAll(figure);

    Scene scene = new Scene(pane,500,700);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Main");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}


public class Figure extends Node {
private Circle circle ;
private Line boldLine ;
private Line thinLine ;
private Line prepenLine ;

public Figure(int centerX, int centerY, int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY){
    Circle circle = new Circle(centerX,centerY,10);
    circle.setStroke(Color.GRAY);
    circle.setFill(Color.DARKGRAY);
   prepenLine = new Line(startX,startY,endX,endY);
}
```

Hi, I was trying to write a class to use my custom nodes like a combo of line and circle but an error keep occuring in show() statement. 
I can't find what is wrong with the code. Any advice?

Edit: provided errors to make it more clear

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Applications should not extend the Node class directly.
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.getHelper(NodeHelper.java:78)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.transformsChanged(NodeHelper.java:121)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.nodeResolvedOrientationInvalidated(Node.java:6540)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.parentResolvedOrientationInvalidated(Node.java:6517)
 etc.
```

Comment: very long one, ends like that : at javafx.stage.Window.show(Window.java:955)
 at javafx.stage.Stage.show(Stage.java:259)
 at Main.start(Main.java:21)
 at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
 at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
 at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 
 ... 1 more
Exception running application Main

Comment: Post the *complete* stack trace in your question. The whole point of a stack trace is that it is there to help you diagnose the problem.

Comment: And don't extends `Node` directly. Creating nodes without adding them to the scene shouldn't really be necessary. BTW: [Edit] the question to add the stacktrace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/Node.html):

> An application should not extend the Node class directly. Doing so may lead to an UnsupportedOperationException being thrown.

In fact, if I try to run your code, the stack trace explicitly says this too:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Applications should not extend the Node class directly.
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.getHelper(NodeHelper.java:78)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.transformsChanged(NodeHelper.java:121)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.nodeResolvedOrientationInvalidated(Node.java:6540)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.parentResolvedOrientationInvalidated(Node.java:6517)
 etc. ...
```

Your `Figure` class really doesn't do anything anyway: it just creates some shapes (`Circle`s and `Line`s), which are private (so inaccessible). Those shapes are never actually displayed by your `Node` class. There is no public API that allows you to determine how a node is painted.

You should probably subclass `Region` (or perhaps `Pane`), and add the shapes as child nodes:

```
public class Figure extends Region {

    private Circle circle ;
    private Line boldLine ;
    private Line thinLine ;
    private Line prepenLine ;

    public Figure(int centerX, int centerY, int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY){
        circle = new Circle(centerX,centerY,10);
        circle.setStroke(Color.GRAY);
        circle.setFill(Color.DARKGRAY);
        prepenLine = new Line(startX,startY,endX,endY);
        getChildren().addAll(circle, prepenLine);
    }

}
```