# Is it allowed to extend the Shape class?

Tags: java, inheritance, javafx, geometry, shapes

I have multiple geometries which extends from a Shape class like this:

```
public class ExtendedLine extends Line {

  private String attribute;

  // more attributes and methods
}
```

```
public class ExtendedCircle extends Circle {

  private String attribute;

  // more attributes and methods
}
```

Now, to access all geometries at once, I defined a super class which extends Shape and contains all attributes and methods which the ExtendedLine and ExtendedCircle have in common. This saves me a lot of redundant code.

```
public class Geometry extends Shape {
  
  private String attribute;
  
  // more attributes and methods
}
```

```
public class ExtendedLine extends Geometry {
}
```

```
public class ExtendedCircle extends Geometry {
}
```

Is it allowed / good practice to extend the Shape class?

Comment: what happened when you tried ;) No it's not allowed, as the doc clearly states (to be honest: that fact was new to me when I first heard about it ;) Extending Node, Shape and Shape3D throws UnsupportedOperationException when showing the extended class, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49905047/cant-show-an-instance-of-an-inherited-node-class

Comment: Some history: Prior to Java 9, the Shape and Node classes had public and/or protected abstract methods that relied on private API (by using classes from the private API as return types and parameter types for those methods). These methods were marked as deprecated as a mechanism to hide them from the API docs, and served as a de-facto way of preventing programmers from subclassing the classes. In Java 9 and later, that is basically prevented by the module system, so some refactoring was done. The documentation was updated to state that an exception would be thrown if a subclass were used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you're talking about the `javafx.scene.shape.Shape` class. If that's correct, then [the documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/18/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/shape/Shape.html)<sup>**1**</sup> says that you should not extend that class:

> An application should not extend the Shape class directly. Doing so may lead to an UnsupportedOperationException being thrown.

However, the class is not final, it has a public constructor, and it has no package-private abstract methods (which you would not be able to override). So, there's nothing physically stopping you from extending `Shape` and compiling the code, but it may not work properly at run-time<sup>**1**</sup>. I would suggest you heed the documentation and don't extend it.

Note other classes have similar documentation (e.g., `javafx.scene.Node`)<sup>**1**</sup>. Likely these classes, if JavaFX were written today, would be `sealed`, with any extendable subclasses being marked `non-sealed`. See [JEP 409: Sealed Classes](https://openjdk.org/jeps/409).

There's another problem with extending `Shape`. When you extend `Line` then your subclass **is** a `Line`, just with the added attributes and methods. But when your e.g., `ExtendedLine` class extends `Shape` (via your `Geometry` class), then it is no longer a `Line`. You can't add it to your scene graph and expect a line to be drawn. That means either drawing the line yourself, or having the subclass wrap a `Line` instance that you can access; but in either case, what was the point of subclassing `Shape` in the first place then?

---

<sup>**1.** For all intents and purposes, you should interpret the documentation as if it said an `UnsupportedOperationException` **will** be thrown, not just **may** be thrown. I can only assume they worded it that way because the exception is only thrown when you add an instance of the direct subclass to the scene graph (at least in my tests), but not every application is guaranteed to attempt that.</sup>

<sup>I tested this with direct subclasses of `javafx.scene.Node`, `javafx.scene.LightBase`, `javafx.scene.shape.Shape`, and `javafx.scene.shape.Shape3D`. All of them resulted in an `UnsupportedOperationException` being thrown when added to the scene graph. There may be other classes with the same "problem", but those are the ones I'm aware of currently.</sup>

Comment: Thank you. So do you have an idea how I could implement my structure? Until now I use an interface to access all geometry classes, but they all have attributes and methods in common, so it's very redundant... I want to loop through them like "for each geometry..." and not "for each line", "for each circle" etc.

Comment: I think that depends on your use case, which I'm not entirely clear on. Perhaps the decorator pattern, as [suggested by jewelsea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73231079/javafx-is-it-allowed-to-extend-the-shape-class/73231845#comment129332466_73231079), would be the best approach. What are you actually trying to _do_ with these custom attributes and methods?

Comment: Let's say each class has attributes(id, name, coordinates...) with getter and setter.
So I would like to do something like this ```for(...) ...geometry.getCoordinates()...```

Comment: One option is to have this information in the model (in an e.g., MVC architecture). But if you want this information contained in your view classes, then perhaps you can make use of [`Node#getProperties()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/18/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#getProperties()) with some static helper methods (e.g., `Helper.getId(theShape)` and `Helper.setId(theShape, newValue)`).

Comment: I use MVC, and the classes are in the Model. For example ExtendedCircle extends Circle with id, coordinates, fillcolor. The same for other geometry classes. Then I use an interface which each geometry class implements to say: for each geometry change size

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something about your setup. The `javafx.scene.shape` classes are view classes. Extending them makes your subclasses view classes as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247025/discussion-between-slaw-and-enrico).

Comment: _So, there's nothing physically stopping you from extending Shape and compiling the code_ true but you can't do anything with them because they indeed  _not work properly at run-time_ because they are throwing the spec'd exception on showing :)

Comment: @kleopatra I worded it that way because the documentation says "may", not "will". Though I would expect a UOE to definitely be thrown if you tried adding the instance to the scene graph.

Comment: yeah, I'm aware of that :) Personally, I think the doc is suboptimal - at least it should have stated that the core implementation definitely will throw. The more lenient description might be chosen to keep open the door for alternative deep re-implementations of basic classes which might allow it